# chrome.tabs.executeScript: How to get access to variable from content script in background script?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

How to get access to variable `app` from content script `app.js` in background script `background.js`?

Here is how I try it (`background.js`):

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, { file: "app.js" }, function() {
   app.getSettings('authorizeInProgress'); //...
});
```

Here is what I get:
[image: Error during tabs.executeScript: Cannot access contents of url "chrome-devtools://devtools/devtools.html?docked=true&dockSide=bottom&toolbarColor=rgba(223,223,223,1)&textColor=rgba(0,0,0,1)". Extension manifest must request permission to access this host. \n Uncaught ReferenceError: app is not defined]

Here is `manifest.json`:

```
{
  "name": "ctrl-vk",
  "version": "0.1.3",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "description": "Chrome extension for ctrl+v insertion of images to vk.com",

  "content_scripts": [{
    "matches": [
        "http://*/*",
        "https://*/*"
    ],
    "js": ["jquery-1.9.1.min.js"
    ],
    "run_at": "document_end"
  }],

  "web_accessible_resources": [
    "jquery-1.9.1.min.js"
  ],

  "permissions" : [
    "tabs",
    "http://*/*",
    "https://*/*"
  ],

  "background": {
    "persistent": false,
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
  }
}
```

## Full code for instance, at github

https://github.com/MaxLord/ctrl-vk/tree/with_bug

Comment: I was figured out, what when we pass first argument as null to executeScript() - this mean that we trying to execute script in *current* tab. It is obviously not we want to get.. We currently need a way how to get this damn tab's id..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To avoid above error use following code

```
if (tab.url.indexOf("chrome-devtools://") == -1) {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabId, {
        file: "app.js"
    }, function () {

        if (app.getSettings('authorizeInProgress')) {
            alert('my tab');
            REDIRECT_URI = app.getSettings('REDIRECT_URI');
            if (tab.url.indexOf(REDIRECT_URI + "#access_token") >= 0) {
                app.setSettings('authorize_in_progress', false);
                chrome.tabs.remove(tabId);
                return app.finishAuthorize(tab.url);
            }
        } else {
            alert('not my');
        }

    });
}
```

instead of

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {
    file: "app.js"
}, function () {

    if (app.getSettings('authorizeInProgress')) {
        alert('my tab');
        REDIRECT_URI = app.getSettings('REDIRECT_URI');
        if (tab.url.indexOf(REDIRECT_URI + "#access_token") >= 0) {
            app.setSettings('authorize_in_progress', false);
            chrome.tabs.remove(tabId);
            return app.finishAuthorize(tab.url);
        }
    } else {
        alert('not my');
    }

});
```

## Explanation

- **`chrome://extensions/`** page also fires `chrome.tabs.onUpdated` event, to avoid it we have to add a filter to skip all dev-tool pages.

Comment: You have to use message passing or return value of array from `executeScript()` function to parse value of content script..

Comment: Where is `tab` variable? I get `Uncaught ReferenceError: tab is not defined`

Comment: I found `tab` in `onUpdated` event. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

(Would've submitted this as comment to the accepted answer but still lack the required reputation)

You should also give the tabId to chrome.tabs.executeScript as first argument when you have it. Otherwise you risk user switching windows/tabs right after requesting a URL and background.js doing executeScript against wrong page.

While fairly obvious on hindsight it threw me for a loop when I got that same error message "Cannot access contents of url "chrome-devtools://.." even though my chrome.tabs.onUpdated eventhandler was checking that the page user requested had some specific domain name just before doing the executeScript call.

So keep in mind, chrome.tabs.executeScript(null,..) runs the script in active window, even if the active window might be developer tools inspector.

Answer (score 0):

We should notice that, in the manifest cofig：

```
"content_scripts": [{
"matches": [
    "http://*/*",
    "https://*/*"
],
"js": ["jquery-1.9.1.min.js"
],
```

in the "matches" part, only http, https are matched, so if you load your extension in page like: 'chrome://extensions/', or 'file:///D:xxx', that error will occur.

You may load your extension in the page with the url 'http://'; or add more rules in your 'matches' array.